# mp.set_start_method('spawn') triggered an error saying the context is already been set

Tags: multiprocessing, google-colaboratory

Here is my full [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11S0q3QcBWzHX4Rxluu2Zu8svd4h4fI_-#scrollTo=tGmZePPYsEM9)

I have succeeded to reproduce the behavior of my main code with a little snippet.

In a **Google Colab Env**, suppose I setup `hardware accelerator` to `GPU`.

Here is the little [snippet](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19mL5jh1CsOaz-SouoelJRc4TkE4KvZUP?usp=sharing) :

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```

With `mp.set_start_method('spawn')`, I got the error `RuntimeError: context has already been set` and if I use `mp.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)` it got stuck in an infinite loop if I can say.

Is there any way I can prevent that error from occurring in the Colab Env?

**P.S.** Be aware `mp.set_start_method('spawn')` this line of code is necessary in my code. Otherwise, I got the error `RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method`

**Overkilled Solution**

[image]

The problem here is that the spawned subprocess can't find `__main__.foo`.

One (less than perfect) option is to put the code in a separate file, e.g. make a new directory and add it to the path.

I don't want to use that solution because it is way overkilled for my main code. Maybe it will guide you to a more elegant solution.

**UPDATE**

This seems to be a more reasonable solution, but still looking for an answer more elegant.

[image]

Comment: Spawned workers aren't going to see anything defined interactively, no matter whether or not you use a context.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Can you suggest a full answer? I have this same exact problem in my main code and I can't solve it. Let me do an update on the question

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am still not sure why it doesn't work so far. I would like a bit more details. If it can't work, is there a workaround?

Comment: 2023 already and still no solution? I'm facing the same problem though I am using a Linux on a VPS with all standard python configuration. Please mention the solution should you had found it already

Answer (score 8):

You should set start method before a function call(except main) as spawn.

Example usage:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

try:
   mp.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
   print("spawned")
except RuntimeError:
   pass
```

I usually use this block for inference with multiprocessing in PyTorch